# Using a condition in ASP MVC3 Html.DisplayFor control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, where-clause

Is there a way to use a condition in the ASP MVC3 `@Html.DisplayFor()` control? Below is the syntax I attempted. While it seems the `partner.TradingPartners` is able to use  `.Where<>`, according to Visual Studio I am doing it wrong!

Here is the syntax I use

```
        @foreach (var item in Model.Agent.SymNumberToAgentId)
        {
            var gogo = ViewBag.Periscope + item.AgentId.Trim();
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DisplayAgentId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompanyCode)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @foreach (var partner in Model.AgentIdDetails)
                    {
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => partner.TradingPartners.Where(item => item.AgentId == partner.AgentId))
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Delete", "SymetraNumberToAgentId", new { id = item.SymetraNumber, aid=item.AgentId}, null)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href=@gogo target="_blank">View in Periscope</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

and here is the error message

> `CS1928: 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>,
>   System.Func<TSource,bool>)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: Much cleaner to filter this list in the controller

Answer (score 2):

Edit: After the question was updated (code inside foreach):

```
      @foreach (var partner in Model.AgentIdDetails)
                    {
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => partner.TradingPartners.Where(x => x.AgentId == item.AgentId).XYZProperty)
                    }
```

---

You need to use Proper syntax in the where clause. Also, you should specify the Property for the filtered Trading Partner.

```
<td>
    @foreach (var partner in Model.AgentIdDetails)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => partner.TradingPartners.Where(item => item.AgentId == partner.AgentId).XYZProperty)
    }
</td>
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, you beat me to it. But I still think it's valid to consider what @Forty-Two said... this is probably better done in the controller.

Comment: True. The best practice is to do it in the controller. +1 to @Forty-Two

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer in my description of the code. This is taking place inside a `foreach` loop

Comment: Ugh.. the edited answer resulted in the following error message: `'string' does not contain a definition for 'AgentId' and no extension method 'AgentId' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: I believe the issue is there is no `AgentId` property in the `TradingPartners` list.